# Chevy el camino 1959 headlight problem

Tags: chevrolet, headlight, lights

I'm Bram from the Netherlands.
At home we have an 1959 Chevy El Camino.
When we have the headlights on after a couple of minutes.
The lights begin to turn off couple of minutes later on, and like that the whole time.

Any of you know What this could be?
I'm a mechanic myself at the Dodge dealer.

Greatings
Bram Hofs

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this an import from the States? Meaning, is the El Camino a US spec'd vehicle? What engine does it have in it? Do you know if it has an alternator or a generator (not sure when GM switched to alternators)?

Comment: Probably start by doing voltage drop testing on the headlight wiring and watching it until the light shuts off.

Comment: Is this one of the vehicles that had a « re-setting » breaker instead of a fuse for the headlights? If so, there may be a short-circuit or has someone « upgraded » the bulbs causing it to be overloaded?

Comment: I second SolarMike, my '76 TR7 also uses it in the headlight circuit, and in the manual, it's called a 'circuit breaker'. You may look for that term in your manual. It's just a self resetting fuse that disables when the current exceeds a certain threshold, only to re-enable after either some time, or after the electrical load has been removed. A wrong type may have been fitted, or it may have broken down partially due to age.